# get missing data from should be identical mysql tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, left-join

I have two tables aka. "t1" and "t2"

Each has 4 columns where the first 3 should be identical aka. "t1.col1 = t2.col1, t1.col2 = t2.col2, t1.col3 = t2.col3"

My problem is that there are missing rows in "t2", how can I extract only the missing rows from "t1" if they do not exist in "t2"

Example:

```
Table1                       Table 2

||one||two||three||four      ||one||two||three||four
||1  ||1  ||1    ||text      ||1  ||1  ||1    ||text
||1  ||1  ||2    ||text      ||1  ||1  ||2    ||text
||1  ||1  ||3    ||text      ||1  ||1  ||3    ||text
||1  ||1  ||4    ||text      ||1  ||2  ||1    ||text
||1  ||2  ||1    ||text      ||1  ||2  ||2    ||text
||1  ||2  ||2    ||text      ||1  ||2  ||3    ||text
```

in table 2 the missing row is "1 || 1 || 4 || text"

I need to retrieve all missing rows only from table 1

Thank You in advance for your time!

Comment: Is there a unique ID on the tables, if not you might have to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN, and use a HAVING clause to exclude all rows that are NOT NULL

Comment: I do not have any unique id's. They were unnecessary for these tables. I knew I would have to do some kind of joining, but I can't wrap my head around how to do it. Both tables have "THOUSANDS" of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 AS A 
LEFT JOIN t2 AS B ON A.one = B.one AND A.two = B.two AND A.three = B.three 
WHERE B.four IS NULL
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank You. I'll answer the question in 4 min

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM t1
WHERE (col1, col2, col3, col4) NOT IN
(SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM t2)
```

Apart from Left joining - this should also work